# Find horisontal, vertical and slant asymptotes of this function...

Tags: limits

$$y=\sqrt{x^2-1}$$

I found that this function has no asymptotes, but I have no idea if it's true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Presumably you're only defining the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2-1}$ for $|x|\geq 1$. There are no horizontal or vertical asymptotes for this function, but there is (at least one) slant asymptote. You should show that
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}
$$
converges to a real number. (Which one?) You can use this to determine the slant asymptote of $y=f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$. Of course you should also determine if
$$
\lim_{x\to-\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}
$$
exists, as well, and if so determine the slant asymptote of $y=f(x)$ as $x\to-\infty$.

Comment: If a slant asymptote is kx+n and I get that k is 1, I can't get the n, I always get it's 0/0.

Comment: Note that by definition $y=kx+n$ is a slant asymptote of the curve $y = f(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ if and only if $\lim_{x\to\infty}(kx+n - f(x)) = 0$, which implies $n = \lim_{x\to\infty}(kx - f(x))$. So in this case, to find $n$ you need to compute $\lim_{x\to\infty}(x-\sqrt{x^2-1})$. Are you getting that this limit is in the indeterminate form $0/0$?